# JavaFX line chart using arrays

Tags: javafx, linechart

I would like to plot LineChart using JavaFX. How can I plot with Array dataset, which means I have two equal length Arrays of doubles X and Y. I want to use these as dataset for the plot.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried example code by Oracle? In the download page of the JDK there are code examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try using that. But I didn't get any examples with arrays.

Comment: You have to convert the array to an XYChart.Series manually. This is just a small loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill the series in a loop:

```
final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

LineChart<Number,Number lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
series.setName("data");
for(int i = 0; i<xArray.length; i++) {
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArray[i], yArray[i]);
}
lineChart.getData().add(series);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I had an unnecessary step in my code. The improved performance over adding data to a Series is not directly due to Collection vs. ObservableList, and I get the same performance when I create an ObservableArrayList and populate the ObservableArrayList directly with the data.

The issue that causes Christian Fries solution to take longer for large sets of data is in the XYChart.Series class. If you look at the source code in JavaFX for XYChart.Series, it has a change listener that goes through all the data, and is activated every time data is added to the series.

Long story short, you can remove 1 line from my original solution, as in the following code, and get the same performance improvement. I will, however, leave my original.

```java
    // Create the graph
    LineChart<Number, Number> graph = new LineChart<Number, Number>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
    
    // Create the list
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    // Add all values from the array into the list
    for (int val : value)
        list.add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(val,val));
    
    // create a series from the list
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>(list);
    
    // Add the series to the graph
    graph.getData().add(series);
```

---

I was looking for a solution to this question, but Christian Fries solution did not work for me, because I had a very large set of data, and it took WAY too long to graph.

After some research, I found the issue is likely due to how the JavaFX Series class works, and that each time you add data to the series, it actually has to reevaluate the validity of ALL the data, because it uses an ObservableList internally, so that each data point added takes longer than the last. Exponential time complexity in other words, which is definitely something to avoid.

I found a better solution is to create a Collection of JavaFX Data, and add the data to this collection. Once fully populated, this collection can then be turned into a JavaFX Series, and graphed as you would normally graph a series. See the following code, where the array is named "value".

```java
    // Create the graph
    LineChart<Number, Number> graph = new LineChart<Number, Number>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
    
    // Create the collection
    Collection<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> collection = new ArrayList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>();
    
    // Put all values from the array into the collection
    for (int val : value)
        collection.add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(val,val));
    
    // Create the data using the collection
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(collection);
    
    // create a series from the list
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>(list);
    
    // Add the series to the graph
    graph.getData().add(series);
```

While the code may seem slightly more complex than Christian Fries, it's actually much more efficient in terms of performance. You can run the following code if you want to see the actual performance Difference, though I wouldn't recommend it, since method #2 takes so long. Also, keep in mind that the second method in the code has exponential time complexity, so the more data there is, the greater the difference in how long it takes.

```java
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Collection;
    
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
    import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    
    public class GraphingImplementation  extends Application
    {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage)
        {
            // close the initial stage.
            stage.close();
            
            // The size of the array
            int seriesSize = 50000;
            
            // Build the graphs
            LineChart<Number, Number> graph1 = new LineChart<Number, Number>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
            LineChart<Number, Number> graph2 = new LineChart<Number, Number>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
            
            // Deactivate features that cause slow down
            graph1.setCreateSymbols(false);
            graph1.setAnimated(false);
            graph2.setCreateSymbols(false);
            graph2.setAnimated(false);
            
            // Create value array to graph.
            int value[] = new int[seriesSize];
            for(int i = 0; i<seriesSize; i++)
                value[i] = i;
            
            
            
            //**********************************************************
            // METHOD #1 - Creation of collection to populate series
            //**********************************************************
            // TIME COMPLEXITY - O{n}
            //**********************************************************
            // Mark the starting time of graphing method #1
            long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            // Create the collection
            Collection<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> collection = new ArrayList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>();
            // Add all values into the collection
            for (int val : value)
                collection.add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(val,val));
            // Create the data using the collection
            ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(collection);
            // create a series from the list
            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>(list);
            // Add the series to the graph
            graph1.getData().add(series);
            // Mark the stopping time of graphing method #1
            long stopTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            // Print the run time for method #1
            System.out.println((stopTime - startTime) + " Milliseconds");
            
            
            
            // build the first scene
            Scene scene1 = new Scene(graph1, 640, 480);
            // create and populate the first stage
            Stage stage1 = new Stage();
            stage1.setScene(scene1);
            // show the first stage
            stage1.show();
            
            
    
            
            //**********************************************************
            // METHOD #2 - Direct creation of a series
            //**********************************************************
            // TIME COMPLEXITY - O{n^2}
            //**********************************************************
            // Mark the starting time of graphing method #2
            startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            // Create the XYChart Series
            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
            // add all values to the series
            for (long val : value)
                series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(val, val));
            // add the series to the graph
            graph2.getData().add(series2);
            // Mark the stopping time of graphing method #2
            stopTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            // Print the run time for method #2
            System.out.println((stopTime - startTime) + " Milliseconds");
            
            
            
            // build the second scene
            Scene scene2 = new Scene(graph2, 640, 480);
            // create and populate the second stage
            Stage stage2 = new Stage();
            stage2.setScene(scene2);
            // show the second stage
            stage2.show();
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            launch(args);
        }
        
    }
```

This code reports the following in the terminal:

75 Milliseconds

89896 Milliseconds

So as you can see, method #1 takes only 75 milliseconds, compared to almost a minute and a half for method #2. Also, the more data you graph, the greater the improvement method #1 will have.

Also, a note if this is of any importance. I am using Java/JavaFX 8.